# Javascript encoding issues when parsing .csv file

Tags: javascript, html, csv

I am having some issues while trying to parse some date from a .csv file using javascript. The issue is simply that some characters appear strangely, as they are country specific and only used in Scandinavia. I have seen several people answer how to fix encoding when creating a .csv with javascript, but I can't make it work when extracting data. This is some of what I have tried:

```
  var fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    var reader = new FileReader();
            reader.onload = function () {

                var data = reader.result;
                var BOM = "\uFEFF"; 
                var csvContent = BOM + csvContent;
    }

    };
            reader.readAsBinaryString(fileInput.files[0]);
```

Comment: if the problem is the data then you should include a sample of the data. without some data, the only thing anyone can do is guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried using [reader.readAsText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsText)?

It should correctly handle utf-8 characters which seems to be your issue.